# How to Access Additional Hidden Regional Themes in Windows 8 like Windows 7 MCT Folder?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-7, themes, windows-8.1

Can anyone tell me How to use the windows 8 hidden themes for different regions like we get in Windows 7?

I tried to do the same. But i couldn't get it.

Or Is it available for Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this feature is not included in Windows 8 – the default theme pack should be the one available for everyone, but there are no others as far as know.